# Run function with class and outside class

Tags: javascript

I have got a function which sets a value within my class and does some other things. I need to run this function from within the class and outside the class.

the function is called `state(val)`. As far as im aware you don't need to add `function` before the name.

Im simply getting an error saying

> state is not defined

Here is my code

```
// Menu control object
    class menuControl {
      constructor(obj, children, items) {
        this.children = children;
        this.elm = obj;
        this.state = 0;
      }

      state(val) {
        this.state = val;
        for(var index in controls) {
          if (index !== not) {
            addClass(controls[index].elm, 'disabled');
          } else {
            removeClass(controls[not].elm, 'disabled');
          }
          if (this.state === 0) {
            removeClass(controls[index].elm, 'disabled');
          }
        }
      }

      toggle() {
        // MENU ACTIVE
        if (this.state === 0) {
          for(var i in this.children) {

            // Add required classes
            if (this.children[i][1] === 1) {
              addClass(this.children[i][0], 'toggled');
            } else {
              removeClass(this.children[i][0], 'toggled');
            }
          }
          this.state(1); // Toggle the state
        } else {

          // MENU INACTIVE
          for(var i in this.children) {
            removeClass(this.children[i][0], 'toggled');
          }

          this.state(0); // Toggle the state
        }
      }
    }
```

**Update**

```
// Menu control object
    class menuControl {
      constructor(obj, children, items) {
        this.children = children;
        this.elm = obj;
        this.state = 0;
      }

      setState(val) {
        this.state = val;
        for(var index in controls) {
          if (index !== not) {
            addClass(controls[index].elm, 'disabled');
          } else {
            removeClass(controls[not].elm, 'disabled');
          }
          if (this.state === 0) {
            removeClass(controls[index].elm, 'disabled');
          }
        }
      }

      toggle() {
        // MENU ACTIVE
        if (this.state === 0) {
          for(var i in this.children) {

            // Add required classes
            if (this.children[i][1] === 1) {
              addClass(this.children[i][0], 'toggled');
            } else {
              removeClass(this.children[i][0], 'toggled');
            }
          }
          setState(1); // Toggle the state <--------- Get the error here
        } else {

          // MENU INACTIVE
          for(var i in this.children) {
            removeClass(this.children[i][0], 'toggled');
          }

          setState(0); // Toggle the state
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: you have a method and a property named `state`. In the constructor you overwrite the (inherited) method with the property.

Comment: I had named the method setState before but got the error: `setState is not defined` @Thomas

Comment: could you show that code, and where you get that error?

Comment: @Thomas added the code above

Comment: in your update, `setState` is not a function, it's a method of `this`. you have to call it that way: `this.setState(1)`. If `addClass` and `removeClass` are also methods of this class, that would also apply to these calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining state twice:

```
  constructor(obj, children, items) {
    this.children = children;
    this.elm = obj;
    this.state = 0; // <--- once as a numeric property
  }

  state(val) {  // <--- ... and once as a method
    this.state = val;
    for(var index in controls) {
      if (index !== not) {
        addClass(controls[index].elm, 'disabled');
      } else {
        removeClass(controls[not].elm, 'disabled');
      }
      if (this.state === 0) {
        removeClass(controls[index].elm, 'disabled');
      }
    }
  }
```

So you would need to give one of the two another name. You could for example call your method `setState`. Using a verb for method names is also helpful to distinguish them from properties.

Comment: I was doing that before but getting the error `setState is not defined` :S